# Unexpected elements alignment with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

**Premise 1**: The pen linked below contains a bunch of code written with AngularJS. Nevertheless, the question is about HTML5+CSS3, so you can safely ignore it.

**Premise 2:** I am developing a web calendar. The calendar is divided in weeks, and features two main parts: a **navigator** (displays the weeks) and a list of **categories** (each category contains some event, and empty cells for the days) See a very basic version [in this pen](http://codepen.io/simonedavico/pen/nlxam?editors=110).

### The problem

I am using [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) in order to develop a layout that adapts to window resize.
My problem is that the navigator's cells (days) and categories' cells (empty placeholders) do not align vertically in the expected way:

[image: Days and placeholder should be aligned!]

As you can see, the cells are not aligned properly. I thought that the problem could reside in the fact that the layout of a category wasn't exactly like the layout of the navigator, since the navigator is divided in weeks. Thus, I divided also empty placeholders in the category, but with no luck.

### The layout

The layour exploits also bootstrap's grid system, and is organized like this (I'll put only the classes, since they are all `div`s):

```
.row .navigator     <-------------------->   .row .category
    .col-1 .navigator-header  <------------->    .col-1 .category-header
    .col-11 .navigator-content   <---------->    .col-11 .category-content
         .week        <------------------------->    .category-group
            .week-header                                (nothing here)
            .days    <------------------------->        .cells
```

I put arrows to associate the elements of a category and the navigator. The only difference is the presence of a `week-header`, but it doesn't have sizes set so SHOULDN'T be relevant. You can check the CSS in the pen, it's really simple.

### The question

The question is: **why are the elements aligned differently? What am I ignoring here?**

In case you need more information, just let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What are you *expecting* it to look like? Do you mean that the cells aren't the same width? That is, the white borders/spacing should line up from one row to the next? So the `16` cell and the `stuff` cell below it should be the same width?

Comment: Cells should be vertically aligned. The first should be exactly under 16, the second exactly under 17, and so on. It should align them by itself, since in both cases it distributes the available space between 42 cells. But for some reason it does not.

Comment: That is often referred to as "horizontal alignment" since it is in regards to the horizontal positioning of the item. And "vertical alignment" would be used to refer to the vertical positioning of the item. (See [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).)

Comment: Oh, right. My bad. I meant "alignment on the vertical axis".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you seem to be running into is the character length of the day numbers (1-31) are different, causing each flex item to start out at a different size. By default, [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) is set to `auto`, which means the initial **main size** of a flex item is dependent upon the contents (in this case, the numbers 1 through 31). In the "Holidays" row, each column has the same contents ("stuff"). So, that's why each "stuff" item has the same width while each day item has a different size based on the width of the number character(s).

In your pen, simply [add `flex-basis:0;` to `.week, .category-group`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rDiwA). This sets the intial **main size** to `0px` and increases the size from there.

Here's a simplified example, showing the issue ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/CX72u/)):

[image: Screenshot showing different between <code>flex:1 1 0</code> and <code>flex:1 1 auto</code>]

```html
<h1>flex:1 1 0;</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">a</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">hello world</div>
</div>
<h1>flex:1 1 auto;</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell auto">a</div>
    <div class="cell auto">a</div>
    <div class="cell auto">a</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell auto">a</div>
    <div class="cell auto">a</div>
    <div class="cell auto">hello world</div>
</div>
```

```css
.row {
    display:flex;
}
.cell {
    flex:1 1 0;
    outline:1px solid red;
}
.cell.auto {
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know this. Thank you! I'll try tomorrow morning and get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Solved it! As you said, it was enough to add `flex-basis` to every element with flex-grow:1`. Now they are properly aligned. Thank you, I completely ignored the existence of this property. If someone wants to take a look at the updated result, I updated the pen linked in the question.